# Delete Larger List items in SPONLINE using workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, ms-flow

I have a large list in Sp Online with over 50k records that's throwing a threshold error when i try to edit anything.I have thought of doing a cleanup and delete historical records that's of no use anymore. can you please assist if i can use workflow to delete older records using Date range?

1) I have tried to reindex the columns that SPONLINE supports.

2) Filter the view with Indexed columns.

3) Avoid using OR within a list view filter.

4) use of AND in filter, GROUP BY functions, and limit list items.

5) Breakdown the ALL_ITEMS Views as much as i can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell for this kind of operation.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url <yourtenant>.sharepoint.com

$listName = "Employee"
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List $listName -Fields "Title","Created","ID","GUID"

// 30 days is the cut off period 
$days = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

foreach($item in $items) 
{
    $created = $item["Created"]

    Write-Host "Item created on $created"
    if($created -gt $days) 
    {
        continue;
    }

    try
    {
        Remove-PnPListItem -List $listName -Identity $item.Id -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "Unable to process delete$($item.Id) in list $listName"
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. To be specific i have this sharepoint Calendar list in Sharepoint Online and have over 10K records which we recently migrated from on-premises environment. as you know Threshold limit were allowed to increase from Central admin in the past and not anymore.and i am planning to delete those records from previous years using a flow or PS Script. i.e  and i would like to delete records based on Date range i.e  and i dont think running in batch is not gonna help in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scheduled flow and then set it to run every day.

Condition: `Created is less than addDays(utcNow(),-365)` Action: `Delete current item`

See a similar post with sample flow here: [Automatically delete files in Document Library after X days.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Automatically-delete-files-in-Document-Library-after-X-days/td-p/70009)

You can also create **retention policies** to manage documents via `Microsoft 365 compliance > Policies > Retention`. (https://compliance.microsoft.com/informationgovernance?viewid=retention)

Reference: [Learn about retention policies for SharePoint and OneDrive.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/retention-policies-sharepoint?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: thank you for your response. To be specific i have this sharepoint Calendar list in Sharepoint Online and have over 10K records which we recently migrated from on-premises environment. as you know Threshold limit were allowed to increase from Central admin in the past and not anymore.and i am planning to delete those records from previous years using a flow. i.e  and i would like to delete records based on Date Column.

Comment: @Khatra Have you checked the first reference in my previous reply? It has a sample flow that should give you a hint.